# Display all the IP Addresses from LAN

Tags: c#, .net

I have to display all the IP Address of my LAN in a ListBox. When i'm trying to bind its empty.

// Code

```
        Process netUtility = new Process(); 
        netUtility.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";

        netUtility.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


        netUtility.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        netUtility.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        netUtility.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        netUtility.Start();



        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(netUtility.StandardOutput.BaseStream);



        string line = "";

        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            if (line.StartsWith("\\"))
            {

                ListBox1.Items.Add(line.Substring(2).Substring(0, line.Substring(2).IndexOf(" ")).ToUpper());

            }

        }

        streamReader.Close();
        netUtility.WaitForExit(1000);
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate, Please look at the following link,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965088/get-all-ips-in-the-same-network-as-my-computer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965088/get-all-ips-in-the-same-network-as-my-computer

Answer (score 1):

Where you can simply use this method much more flexible and easy to use / understand :

C# code:
from this link : [Get All IP Addresses on Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271724/get-all-ip-addresses-on-machine)

```
    // Get host name
String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();

// Find host by name
IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);

// Enumerate IP addresses
int nIP = 0;
foreach(IPAddress ipaddress in iphostentry.AddressList)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a line in the Process.

// Code

```
  netUtility.StartInfo.Arguments = "view";
```

Now it works fine!!!